# How to add values for Java generic Map with undetermined "?" value type?

Tags: java, dictionary, generics, types

I've seen this kind of declaration in JDK 8 sample:

```
Map<String, ?> map = new HashMap<>(3);   // OK
```

But when I tried to add value to `map`, I didn't succeed:

```
map.put("abc", Optional.of(5));
map.put("kk", "xyz");
```

Both fail to compile. I wish to know:

1) What does `?`indicate in `Map` declaration above?

2) How to give values to this `map`?

Comment: `?` is the *unknown* type is java. You cannot add to what is unknown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Question (1)**

```
? is called wildcard generic type.It can be used with any type,
but you need to specify type fist as Map is an abstract class.
```

**Question (2)**

**for  you to give value to this map its either you use Upper bound or Lower bound.**

The following are guidelines when using upper bound or lower bound

```
? extends Type   - is used for read access only
? super Type     - is used for write access only.
```

**PECS** in short **Produces**(write acccess) -uses  **Extends** while **Consumes**(read access) - **uses Super**

```
Map<String, ? super Object> map = new HashMap<>(3);//OK
    map.put("abc",Optional.of(5));
    map.put("kk","xyz");
map.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println(k+"\t"+v));
```

Output

```
kk  xyz
abc Optional[5]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Additional Notes**

**Unbounded wildcard** ?

```
 List<?> l = new ArrayList<String>();
```

**Wildcard with an upper bound** ? extends type

```
 List<? extends Exception> l = new ArrayList<RuntimeException>();
```

**Wildcard with a lower bound** ? super type

```
 List<? super Exception> l = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Answer (score 10):

`Map<String,?>` is an abstract type.  If a variable has this type, it could reference an object with any of the following types (and others).

- `HashMap<String,Integer>`
- `TreeMap<String,String>`
- `HashMap<String,ArrayList<Boolean>>`
- `TreeMap<String,Throwable>`

Obviously, the possibilities are basically endless.  If you have a variable of this type, you know that it refers to a map whose keys are `String`, but you really know nothing else.  In particular, you don't know what type of object you'll end up with when you do a `get` on that `Map`.

More importantly though, you will never be able to `put` anything into the map, without some kind of nasty, unsafe casting operation.  The compiler will stop you.  So in the examples you've given -

- `map.put("abc", Optional.of(5));` won't compile, because `map` could be a `HashMap<String,String>`, into which you can't put an `Optional`.
- `map.put("kk", "xyz");` won't compile, because `map` could be a `TreeMap<String,Integer>`, into which you can't put a `String`.

The exceptions would be `null`, or any value that has come from the map itself - see Andy Turner's excellent answer for more detail about those possibilities.

In short, if you have a variable of type `Map<String,?>`, the operations that the compiler will let you do to it are a bit limited.  You can't put anything into the map, unless it's `null` or it's already in the map.  All you can do is get values from the map, and remove values from the map.

So using a `Map<String,?>` variable is very limiting.  If all you want to do with the map is read values from it, this is just fine, of course.  But don't expect to be able to insert arbitrary values into the map, unless you use a different expression to refer to the map.

Comment: Please don't refer to the wildcard-bounded map as "read-only". For one thing, you can remove elements; for another, you can add elements (see my answer).

Comment: @Andy You're quite right.  I was just reading (and upvoting) your answer.  I'd never thought about adding a value that had come from the map itself.  I'll re-word that part.

Comment: I wonder what use this construct has. I could imagine an abstract class defining a method with this as return type, but any implementation I can come up with would violate either the liskov-substitution-principle or the open-closed principle. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)

Comment: Well, @tgr, you can write methods which treat the map as read-only.  For example, you could write a method that prints all the values in the map.

Comment: Agreed, printing is a mechanism, that would work without taking any assumptions on the value types. But besides that? I cannot see much value of a read-only map, whose values need to be casted for further use.

Comment: @tgr If you were developing a library full of utility methods that operate on maps, you might use this kind of construction in much of the API.

Comment: @tgr `?` is merely a shortened form of the upper bound `? extends Object`. If you were to define a different upper bound, for example `Map<String, ? extends List<Integer>>`, you could use the values of that map without explicit casting. That `?` has very limited uses - in the same way that `Object` has very limited uses - does not mean that wildcards are limited in their usefulness.

Comment: @tgr it is also worth noting that wildcards should pretty much only occur in method parameters, in order to increase the flexibility of the API with respect to the parameters it accepts. You wouldn't define a class with a wildcard, so LSP and OCP aren't really relevant.

Answer (score 7):

`?` is an unknown type: you don't know exactly what it is at that point in the code.

Because of that, you cannot safely add any value to the map, with a couple of exceptions.

You can add literal `null` (because `null` can be cast to any type):

```
map.put("abc", null); // compiles
```

Also, you can add a value to the map which you obtain from the map:

```
<T> void reAdd(Map<String, T> map) {
  T value = map.get("123");
  map.put("456", value);
}

// Call with
reAdd(map); // compiles
```