# Convert T parameter to the appropriate concrete type

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

I have an abstract class and two subclasses that extend it.

```
public abstract class StudentResponseReport<E> {
    private long id;
    private long roundId;
    // ...

    public abstract E getResponse();
}

public class StudentResponseReportSAQ extends StudentResponseReport<String> {
    // ...
}

public class StudentResponseReportMCQ extends StudentResponseReport<Collection<Integer>> {

}
```

Then I have a generic method with this signature.

```
public <T> StudentResponseReport<?> convert(long roundId, T response) {
    // If T is a String, then create an instance of StudentResponseReportSAQ
    // If T is a Collection<Integer>, then create an instance of StudentResponseReportMCQ
}
```

What I want is to create the corresponding subtype given the actual type parameter.

I need to use java generics and type system and don't want any unchecked warnings and casts since they are not type safe.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Just overload the method for String and Collection. No need for it to be generic. At least no with your current signature

Comment: @ernest_k It was a mistake. I have changed the question.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala you cannot have the generic type of the generic type (e.g. Integer for the Collection). Is that ok for you?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo This is a service contract, so I am a bit reluctant to have one method for each concrete type since that solution is bit more verbose and needs me to change the service class for every new type introduced.

Comment: Try this one it should give you an idea on how to use generics https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54086274/how-to-add-values-for-java-generic-map-with-undetermined-value-type/54086770#54086770

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you cannot, at least with complex generic types such as `Collection<Integer>`.
The `Integer` type is not reified, that means you'll be able to see it only as `Object`.

The only way for you to know that the `Collection` is carrying a certain type of data is by having at least one element contained.

The best you can have is something similar to

```
private static final Map<Class<?>, Function<Object, Class<? extends StudentResponseReport<?>>>>
        TYPES = new IdentityHashMap<>();

static {
    TYPES.put(String.class, object -> StudentResponseReportSAQ.class);
    TYPES.put(Collection.class, object -> {
        final var collection = (Collection<?>) object;
        final var element = collection.stream()
                                      .findFirst()
                                      .orElse(null);

        if (element != null && Integer.class.isAssignableFrom(element.getClass())) {
            return StudentResponseReportMCQ.class;
        }

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("...");
    });
}

private <T> StudentResponseReport<?> convert(
        final long roundId,
        final T response)
throws NoSuchMethodException,
       IllegalAccessException,
       InvocationTargetException,
       InstantiationException {
    for (final var entry : TYPES.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey().isAssignableFrom(response.getClass())) {
            final var classToInstantiate = entry.getValue().apply(response);
            // Pass whatever you want to the constructor
            return classToInstantiate.getConstructor().newInstance();
        }
    }

    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("...");
}
```

And that is only with two types. I really don't recommend doing this.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seems the good idea to use wildcard as return type. According to [wildcard guidelines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html)

> Using a wildcard as a return type should be avoided because it forces
>   programmers using the code to deal with wildcards.

In this case, you've to deal with `StudentResponseReport<?>` in the calling code, but you couldn't verify which type is it. From [restrictions of generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html):

> you cannot verify which parameterized type for a generic type is being
>   used at runtime

I think the overloading is the most suitable solution, if it can be applied in your case. Despite the fact that it's verbose.

```
public Collection<StudentResponseReport<String>> convert(long roundId, String response) {
    // Create an instance of StudentResponseReportSAQ
}

public Collection<StudentResponseReport<Collection<Integer>> convert(long roundId, Collection<Integer> response) {
    // Create an instance of StudentResponseReportMCQ
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public <T> StudentResponseReport<T> convert(long roundId, T response) {
        // If T is a String, then create an instance of StudentResponseReportSAQ
        // If T is a Collection<Integer>, then create an instance of StudentResponseReportMCQ

        StudentResponseReport<T> srr = null;

        if (response instanceof String) {
            // T is a String, create StudentResponseReportSAQ

            return srr;
        }

        if (response instanceof Collection) {
            Collection c = (Collection) response;

            if (c.isEmpty()) {
                // optimistically assume that the type argument of the Collection is Integer as we can't verify it, create StudentResponseReportMCQ, or throw a runtime exception (I'll go with the former although the latters a better choice)
                return srr;
            } else if (c.stream().findAny().get().getClass().equals(Integer.class)) {
                // its a subtype of Collection<Integer>, create StudentResponseReportMCQ

                return srr;
            }
        }
        // unexpected type
        throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected Class!");

    }
```

Other answers have done a good job of explaining of why overriding is the way to go and I'll second it.